Beckhoff TF6760 library used with CX9020 throws error Socket_Err_no_conn
I am trying to run a code on my cx 9020 (ARM Controller Windows CE 7 - Build 4024.53) using twincat 3 (build 4024.64). I have to call a rest api POST method. the code runs without errors and a build is produced and loaded into plc. in run mode i receive an error Socket_Err_No_Connection in one of the flags and I believe this what is creating this error.
I wrote a code from an online example I am using twincat CX9020 PLC I followed all the instructions and ended up receiving the socket error socket_err_no_conn.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
